# Дата следующего дня Java

Tags: java, дата

Решал задачу, у которой следующие условия:

• Программа запрашивает сегодняшнюю дату и выдает дату
следующего дня

• Например, входные данные: 31 12 2015, на выходе:
01.01.2016

• День, месяц и год можно запрашивать у пользователя с
консоли по очереди

• Еще сделать проверку даты на корректность

Вроде всё написал правильно, но после сдачи на проверку, сказали: "Лучше сначала получить количество дней во введенном месяце, а только затем делать проверку корректности даты и вычислять следующую дату, тогда код очень сильно упростится". Ни в какую не могу понять, где я должен получить количество дней ***!перед проверкой!***, чтобы упростить код. Буду крайне благодарен за помощь.

Вот код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NextDate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Введите день:");
        int day = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Введите месяц:");
        int month = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Введите год:");
        int year = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("Вы ввели дату - %02d.%02d.%d%n", day, month, year);
        boolean isLeapYear = (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0;

        if ((year % 4 != 0 && month == 2 && day > 28) || (isLeapYear && month == 2 && day > 29)
                || (day > 30 && (month == 2 || month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11))
                || day > 31 || month > 12 || month < 1 || day < 1) {
            System.out.println("Это некорректная дата.");
        } else if (day == 31 && (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10)) {
            month++;
            System.out.printf("Дата следующего дня - 01.%d.%d", month, year);
        } else if (day == 30 && (month == 2 || month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)) {
            month++;
            System.out.printf("Дата следующего дня - 01.%d.%d", month, year);
        } else if ((!isLeapYear && day == 28 && month == 2)
                || (isLeapYear && day == 29 && month == 2)) {
            month++;
            System.out.printf("Дата следующего дня - 01.%d.%d", month, year);
        } else if (day == 31) {
            year++;
            System.out.printf("Дата следующего дня - 01.01.%d", year);
        } else {
            day++;
            System.out.printf("Дата следующего дня - %02d.%02d.%d", day, month, year);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Если через готовый класс LocalDate, то так: `LocalDate.of(year, month, day).plusDays(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Немного переписал код в блокноте, потому за корректность не уверен, но выглядит короче =)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Введите день:");
    int day = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Введите месяц:");
    int month = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Введите год:");
    int year = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.printf("Вы ввели дату - %02d.%02d.%d%n", day, month, year);
    boolean isLeapYear = (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0;

    int maxDay = 30;
    if (month == 2) maxDay= (isLeapYear?29:28);
    if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8 || month == 10 || month == 12) maxDay = 31;

    if (day > maxDay || month > 12 || month < 1 || day < 1) {
        System.out.println("Это некорректная дата.");
    } else if (day == maxDay) {
        month++;
        if (month > 12) {
            month = 1;
            year++;
        }
        System.out.printf("Дата следующего дня - 01.%d.%d", month, year);
    } else {
        day++;
        System.out.printf("Дата следующего дня - %02d.%02d.%d", day, month, year);
    }
}
```